# devise after_sign_in update attributes with geocoder and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise, rails-geocoder

When a user logs in to the website I want geocoder to take the current_sign_in_ip and convert it to the usable latitude: longitude: how can I do this?

my User model-

```
geocoded_by :current_sign_in_ip
after_validation :geocode, :if => :current_sign_in_ip_changed?
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to let geocode record down the latitude and longitude. You need to add latitude and longitude fields to your db table. Let say you using `users` table.

First add the migration

```
rails generate migration AddLatitudeLongitudeToUsers
```

Modify the migration as follow

```
class AddLatitudeLongitudeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :latitude, :float
    add_column :users, :longitude, :float
  end
end
```

Run `rake db:migrate` to save the change.

Add the following geocode setting to user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :current_sign_in_ip
  after_validation :geocode, if: :current_sign_in_ip_changed?
end
```

As most of us testing and develop app in our local machine, current_sign_in_ip will record down as "127.0.0.1" after you sign in.

You can verify it from rails console `rails c`

```
u = User.find_by_email("your_login@email.com")
u.current_sign_in_ip
u.latitude
u.longitude
```

To see whether geocoder work or not, let change the ip manually

```
u.current_sign_in_ip = "199.182.122.98"
u.save
u.latitude
u.longitude
```

> After you sign in, please make sure current_sign_in_ip field has ip record down. Otherwise, the latitude and longitude field will be nil.

Comment: I've done all of that but the latitude and longitude are still nill

Comment: no, because I am trying to geocode after sign_in on my website. so, if someone logs in I recieve their ip and change it to latitude, longitude.

Comment: Did you tried to view the current_sign_in_ip field from rails console? What ip you got? Or may be you can change your user model setting for this line `after_validation :geocode, if: :current_sign_in_ip_changed? ` to `after_validation :geocode ` and use the rails console manually update the current_sign_in_ip with real ip. You should see the latitude and longitude got update then.